# How do I post a json array with retrofit2? For example,

Tags: android, arrays, post, retrofit, retrofit2

i have similar issue,

API require to send like this

```
checkpoin=[{"id":"1907","gps":"31213123,3131231","status":"1"}]
```

I successfully created:

```
[{"id":"1907","gps":"31213123,3131231","status":"1"}]
```

and retrofit configs are like this

```
@POST("save_clockings")Observable<ResponseSaveCehckpoint> saveChekpoint (
      @Query(value = "checkpoint" ,encoded = true) List<JsonObject> checkpoint);
```

but i look with HTTP logging

URL like this

```
https://my.domain.com/api/save_clockings?checkpoint={%22id%22:%221907%22,%22gps%22:%2231213123,3131231%22,%22time%22:%221532674384157%22,%22status%22:%221%22}
```

i send via insomnia that's success, 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7jLE.png)

why retrofit convert character (") to (%22);

can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: [link](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1199)

Comment: Make a getter setter(pojo) class for json and for posting use ```@Field(YourPojoclass pojoobj)```, then it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@POST("save_clockings") Observable<ResponseSaveCehckpoint> saveChekpoint(@Query(value = "checkpoint") List<JsonObject> checkpoint);
```

remove `encoded = true` so it will not encode your `"` to `%22`

as you describe this changes made solve your problem..

```
Request request = original.newBuilder()
   .header("User-Agent", "Accept-Encoding")
   .addHeader("accept-charset", "utf-8")
   .method(original.method(), original.body())
   .build();
```

Comment: i have try that, but it's not working, 

it sove with add header in okhttp like this
 ` Request request = original.newBuilder().header("User-Agent", "Accept-Encoding").addHeader("accept-charset", "utf-8).method(original.method(), original.body()).build();`